# union on the same table

Tags: sql, union

I have a table:

```
ID | Id1 | Id2
1  | 100 | 12
2  | 196 | 140
3  | 196 | 141
4  | 150 | 140
5  | 150 | 199
```

I want to write a query that will give me a table containing records with the same ID2 and with id1 equal to 196 or 150.
I thought about union:

select * from table where ID1 = 196
   union 
   select * from table where ID1 = 150

but that doesn't cover the ID2 requirement.
How should I do that?

Comment: your example query uses "itemid", which isn't in your example table, which is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly then this should be the answer:

```
select * from mytable where id2 in
(select id2 from mytable
group by id2
having count(*)>=2)
and (id1=196 or id1=150)
```

Comment: It's almost good;) Below valid solution:
select * from mytable where id2 in
(select id2 from mytable
where (id1=196 or id1=150)
group by id2
having count(*)>=2)
and (id1=196 or id1=150)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing a `union`?

You could accomplish the same task with `in`.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Id1 IN (196, 150) OR Id2 IN (196, 150)
```

Comment: but i don't know the id2 values.

Comment: I can't explicitly ask about id2 values.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID
FROm yourTable as table1
INNER JOIN yourTable as table2
ON table1.Id2 = table2.Id2
WHERE table1.id1 IN (196.150)
```

here we go

Comment: can you tell me which ID you'd like to get as result  ? maybe it would help me to udnerstand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table to itself

```
 select T1.* from Mytable T1 inner join MyTable T2 
 ON T1.ID2 = T2.ID2
 AND T1.ID1 in (196, 150)
```

Something like that, depending on your exact requirement and table structures you may need to do a little more work to avoid duplicate entries.