# ibatis error with in sql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, ibatis

```
select 
                ID,NAME,SEX,RESIDENCE,EMAIL,MOBILE,PASSWORD,MOOD,BIRTHDAY,AVATAR,TYPE,MONEY
             from 
                user 
             where 
                ID in
                    (select USER2 as id from friend where USER1=#userId# and STATUS= 1 union select user1 as id from friend where user2 = #userId#  )



select 
                ID,NAME,SEX,RESIDENCE,EMAIL,MOBILE,PASSWORD,MOOD,BIRTHDAY,AVATAR,TYPE,MONEY
             from 
                user 
             where 
                ID in
                    (select USER2 as id from friend where USER1=#userId# and STATUS= 1）
```

If i use the second sql it is ok, if I use first, it runs error.I think parameter is ok as the two sql have same parameters

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: SqlMapClient operation; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [null]; error code [0];   
--- The error occurred in com/bit/hapin/dao/activity/activity.xml.  
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.  
--- Check the getInviteFriendForActivity-InlineParameterMap.  
--- Check the parameter mapping for the 'userId' property.  
--- Cause: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1; nested exception is com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:   
--- The error occurred in com/bit/hapin/dao/activity/activity.xml.  
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.  
--- Check the getInviteFriendForActivity-InlineParameterMap.  
--- Check the parameter mapping for the 'userId' property.  
--- Cause: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:121)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:212)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.executeWithListResult(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:249)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.queryForList(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:296)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.queryForList(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:290)
    at com.bit.hapin.dao.activity.ActivityDAOImpl.getInviteFriendForActivity(ActivityDAOImpl.java:51)
```

So what should I do?

Comment: could please `parameter map` and its java classes?

Comment: `Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
   map.put("userId", this.getUserId());
   map.put("activityId", this.getActivityId());`    I don't think there is something wrong with parameter map as I use the same parameter everything is ok

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in first query. But,

In first query :

```
select USER2 as id from friend ..... select user1 as id from friend ....
```

Which mean `friend` table have `USER2` and `user1` columns. If so, make sure tables columns (USER2, user1) in `friend` table. Although I don't know your program requirement, the second query(in your post) is enough because of you are trying to `union` with `single/same` table.

You can also reference : [Union on the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965174/union-on-the-same-table)

Comment: If user1 = userId, I want user2. And if user2 = userId, I want user1. I know there is other solutions, but I still want to know why it goes wrong